# Installing Theme with Version Change Only Causes Additional Main Menu Items to Appear

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've created a copy of a working theme, updated the version number in styles.css, zipped the theme, and uploaded and activated it.

Six additional pages are now appearing in my Main Menu, none of which are in my Menus/Main Menu list. They seem to be the 6 most recent news items, none of which have parent page attributes.

The question is: with exactly the same theme contents (except for the new version number in styles.css), why would this not be propogating itself currently in our production version?

Comment: Assign the custom menu you created to the main navigation location and it should fix it. If that does not work, we need more details.

Answer (score 1):

When you activate a new theme any custom menus will get messed up.

Check your nav menus (Appearance -> Menus) and ensure that they are properly configured as before and that "Automatically add new top level pages" is unchecked.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - will upvote this if unchecking that option seems to fix it, as the nav menus are configured correctly